# Delete many to many data changes after form save (save_m2m)

Tags: python, django

I am using `m2m_changed` but still I cant observe clear changes to the data(what have been added, what have been removed) after `form.save_m2m`.

But if I am adding them individually (.add, .remove) etc I can see the changes.

So, what is the best way for this ? Should I remove `form.save_m2m` and update many to many records manually(`.add`, `.remove`) so the signals will work and I can track the changes ?

Code here:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=ModelName.abc.through)
def func(sender, instance, action, model, pk_set, *args, **kwargs):
    print pk_set - Its printing what I have submitted recently but not showing what is added newly and what is removed newly. I tried with all different actions(pre_add, post_add etc). This function is being called for all those actions.
```

Saving part:

```
form.save()
form.save_m2m()
```

Comment: Please share some code so we dont have to guess what you are talking about...

Comment: Code added ..................